# CSS transition-duration: Is is valid to leave the zero before the dot out?

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have seen that often in other people's code.

Writing ...

```
transition: opacity .6s;
```

... instead of ...

```
transition: opacity 0.6s;
```

Both work (as it seems).

But I wonder:

Is is valid to leave the before-dot zero out?

What's the meaning of these syntax at all?

Is it just a matter of taste? Trying to use the smallest amount of chars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's absolutely valid. Anyway while compiling both .6s and 0.6s considered to be same

Answer (score 4):

Per https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#integers:

> 4.2. Real Numbers: the <number> type
>
> Number values are denoted by <number>. A number is either an <integer> or zero or more decimal digits followed by a dot (.) followed by one or more decimal digits and optionally an exponent composed of "e" or "E" and an integer. It corresponds to the <number-token> production in the CSS Syntax Module [CSS3SYN]. As with integers, the first character of a number may be immediately preceded by - or + to indicate the number’s sign.

From the quote above:

> A number is either an <integer> or zero or more decimal digits followed by a dot (.) followed by one or more decimal digits

it would seem that a number is also valid if it starts with a dot (.), as long as there is at least one decimal digit following the  dot(.).

Answer (score 2):

Yes its absolutely valid 0.6 and .6 are still the floats. 0.6 is preferred

Comment: Care to share why `0.6` is preferred over `.6`?

Comment: code looks more neat and complete , it just a developer perspective, otherwise you can use either of the two